# Does pbpaste empty the clipboard under some circumstances?

Tags: macos, command-line

The [manual for pbcopy and pbpaste](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html) reads as follows:

> **`pbpaste`** removes the data from the pasteboard and writes it to the standard output.

The wording read odd as *remove* for me carries the connotation that the clipboard would be empty after the operation. However, after trying a number of argument combinations, `pbpaste` has consistently worked as one would expect pasting to work – leaving the clipboard intact.

Are there some circumstances under which `pbpaste` will in fact empty the clipboard or is it simply bad wording in the manpage?

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, `pbpaste` is [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation) - it doesn't change the paste bin whether you call it once or many times. The wording in the manual page is unfortunate and maybe filing a bug report with Apple will get it fixed if enough people argue for that change.